# Required data type is wrong

Tags: java

I'm trying to pass an object to the addPhoto method from another class, so I can add it to the photos array, but my IDE keeps telling me the required data type is "Memory" and not photograph. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Memory {
    private Memory[] photographs;
    private int num_Photo;
    private double zoom;
    private String date;

    public Memory(int size, String date){       //set photograph array size and date
        if(size >= 16){
            photographs = new Memory[size];
        }
        else{
            photographs = new Memory[16];
        }
        if(date.length() == 8){
            this.date = date;
        }
        else{
            this.date = "19000101";
        }

    }
    public void setDefault(){                    //set defaults
        this.photographs = new Memory[16];
        this.num_Photo = 0;
        this.zoom = 1.0;
        this.date = "19000101";
    }
    public int getNum_Photo(){            //returns number of photos, part D
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < photographs.length; i++){
            if(photographs[i] != null){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public double getZoom(){ // Getter for zoom
        return this.zoom;
    }
    public void setZoom(double num){ //Setter for zoom
        if(num >= 1.0 && num <= 4.0){
            this.zoom = num;
        }

    }
    public String getDate(){ //Getter for date
        return this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(String num){ //Setter for date
        if(num.length() == 8){
            this.date = num;
        }
        else{
            this.date = "19000101";
        }
    }
    public boolean addPhoto(Photograph p1){ //Adds a photo to array in first available pos
        for(int i = 0; i < photographs.length; i++){
            if(photographs[i] != null){
                photographs[i] = p1 = Photograph.createMinimumPhotograph();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of the class `Photograph`?

Answer (score 2):

You have a

```
Photograph p1
```

as argument of addPhoto; and you have a

```
private Memory[] photographs;
```

¿Did you see the diff?

```
photographs[i] = p1 = Photograph.createMinimumPhotograph();
```

Photograph object in Memory array.

Answer (score 1):

From the code, *photographs* is an array of type Memory. Try changing it to an array of photographs. Instead of `private Memory[] photographs;` use `private Photograph[] photographs`